# How to reach javascript object property

Tags: javascript

I have some radio buttons like to

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked" value="0" id="paramsmenu_images0" name="params[menu_images]">
```

I would like to reach this in javascript somehow like this:

```
console.log(document.adminForm.params[menu_images]);
```

Of course it doesn't work, so how can I reach it?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Are you trying to get the string `menu_images` out of the name attribute?  Or are you trying to get the element where `name="params[theme]"`?

Comment: I have a json object, which contains some default values and I iterate trhough on this list. The list contains the field names and the values, so I have to reach the elements by name. It works fine for text input, but for other inputs I have to write specific codes in the cycle. I would like to reach it somehow like this: console.log(document.adminForm.params[menu_images]);

Comment: What's wrong with `getElementsByName`?

Comment: I think that is one of the oldest FAQ entries for clj use:   
console.log(document.adminForm['params[menu_images]'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this OK?

```
document.getElementsByName('params[menu_images]')
```

You can also iterate over `document.adminForm.elements` to find your form element...

Comment: getElementsByName returns a collection, so:

document.getElementsByName('params[menu_images]')[0]

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('paramsmenu_images0')` will give you the dom element if that's what you want.